# Rails UJS data-disable-with return result

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3's UJS (which is awesome btw). I have the following form HTML:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/invitation" class="simple_form form-invite" data-remote="true" method="post">
   <input class="btn btn-mini btn-invite" data-disable-with="Inviting" name="commit" type="submit" value="Invite">
</form>
```

I'm using `data-disable-with`so the button text changes and button is disabled during processing. However, I'd like the button text to change to "Invited" after the call is complete.

I'm using the following:

```
  $(document).on "ajax:success", ".form-invite", (evt, data, status, xhr) ->
    el = $(this).find('.btn-invite')
    el.val("Invited")
    return
```

This does change the button text. However, since it's processing within the `ajax:success` block, the button text reverts back to "Invite". Is there any way to define the button text after processing using HTML attribute or JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this with a minor hack:

```
$(document).on("ajax:success", ".form-invite", function(evt, data, status, xhr) {
  var el;
  el = $(this).find('.btn-invite');
  setTimeout((function() {
    return el.val("Invited");
  }), 1);
});
```